# How to get more accuracy of the logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, audio-processing, binary-classification, logistic-regression

I am working on a **Baby Crying Detection model** using **logistic regression**.

Out of $581$ audios, $222$ are of a baby crying. Each audio is of $5$ seconds.

what I have done is convert each audio into numbers. and those numbers go into a `.csv` file. so first I took $100$ samples from each audio, then $1000$ samples, and then all $110250$ samples into a `.csv` file, and at the end of each of them was a number 1 (crying) or 0 (not crying). Then I trained the model using logistic regression from that `.csv` file.

The **Problem** I m facing is that with $100$ samples the **64% accuracy** on each audio,  while with 1000 samples and 110250 samples(Full dataset) it reaches to **66% accuracy** only. *How can I improve the accuracy of my model to upto 80% using logistic regression.*

I can only use simple **logistic regression** because I have to deploy the model on **Arduino**.

Comment: How are you processing the raw audio samples "into numbers". For audio processing this is typically some variant of FFT power spectrums. MFCC has been popular for speech. Are you doing anything like that? Please explain more about the pre-processing before reaching the predictive model and [edit] those details into the question. In addition, is sampling triggered by anything (such as hitting a volume threshold)? Or is sampling done at fixed intervals?

Comment: Simply i use librosa library to get audio files into an array. then that array is pasted into a CSV file. I know about MFCC. lets say i pick 100 samples. I pick 100 samples at equal intervals, then those 100 samples per audio (100x581 table of total audios) go through logistic regression which gives output of 100 weights or coefficients. Then arduino takes 100 samples from live recording, these 100 samples and trained model 100 samples are multiplied one to one, then added, then sigmoid function is applied. if output value is greater than 0.5 it means baby is crying. my friend told this method

Comment: i cannot use MFCC because i need to deploy the model on arduino and all the calculation on arduino needs 100 weights, while MFCC outputs just one value per audio

Answer (score 2):

### **Try Rectification**

Improve the **features** available to your model, **Remove** some of the **NOISE** present in the data.

- In audio data, a common way to do this is to **smooth** the data and then **rectify** it so that the total amount of sound energy over time is more **distinguishable**.

```
# Rectify the audio signal
audio_rectified = audio.apply(np.abs)
```

- You can also calculate the **absolute value** of each time point. This is also called **Rectification** because you ensure that all time points are positive.
- Smooth your data by taking the **`rolling`** mean in a **window** of say 50 samples

```
audio_rectified_smooth = audio_rectified.rolling(50).mean()
```

- Calculating the **envelope** of each sound and smoothing it will eliminate much of the noise and you have a cleaner signal.

### **Calculate Spectrogram**

- Calculate a **spectrogram** of sound(i.e combining of windows Fourier transforms). This describes what **spectral content** (e.g., *low and high pitches*) are present in the sound over time. there is a lot more information in a spectrogram compared to a raw audio file. By computing the spectral features, you have a much better idea of what's going on.

  - this is similar to how we calculate **rolling mean** :

    - We calculate **multiple Fourier transforms** in a **sliding window** to see how it changes over time. For each time point, we take a window of time around it, calculate a Fourier transform for the window, then slide to the next window. The result is a description of the **Fourier transform** as it changes throughout the **time-series** called a short-time Fourier transform or STFT.

      - Choose a windows **size** and **shape**
      - At a timepoint, calculate the **FFT** for that window
      - Slide the window over by one
      - Aggregate the results
  - **Calculating the STFT**

    - We can calculate the STFT with `librosa` $\rightarrow$ `import librosa as lr`
    - There are several parameters we can tweak (such as **window size**)
    - For our purposes, we'll convert into **decibels** which **normalizes** the average values of all frequencies.
    - We can then visualize it with the `specshow()` function

This is how you can calculate the **STFT**

```
# Calculating the STFT
# Import the functions we'll use for the STFT
from librosa.core import stft, amplitude_to_db
from librosa.display import specshow

# Calculate our STFT
HOP_LENGTH = 2**4
SIZE_WINDOW = 2**7
audio_spec = stft(audio, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH, n_fft=SIZE_WINDOW)

# Convert into decibels for visualization
spec_db = amplitude_to_db(audio_spec)

# Visualize
specshow(spec_db, sr=sfreq, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz', hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)
```

### **Try Spectral feature engineering**

you can also perform the Spectral feature engineering on your baby audio data

- since each time series has a different spectral pattern.
- We can calculate these spectral patterns by analyzing the spectrogram.
- For example, **spectral bandwidth** and **spectrum centroids** describe where most of the energy is at each moment in time.

```
# Calculate the spectral centroid and bandwidth for the spectrogram
bandwidths = lr.feature.spectral_bandwidth(S=spec)[0]
centroids = lr.feature.spectral_centroid(S=spec)[0]
 
# Display these features on top of the spectrogram
ax = specshow(spec, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz', hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)
ax.plot(times_spec, centroids)
ax.fill_between(times_spec, centroids - bandwidths / 2,centroids + bandwidths / 2, alpha=0.5)
```

Now you can Combine spectral(`spec` $\rightarrow$ spectral dataframe) and temporal features in a classifier

```
centroids_all = []
bandwidths_all = []
 
for spec in spectrograms:
    bandwidths = lr.feature.spectral_bandwidth(S=lr.db_to_amplitude(spec))
    centroids = lr.feature.spectral_centroid(S=lr.db_to_amplitude(spec))
    # Calculate the mean spectral bandwidth
    bandwidths_all.append(np.mean(bandwidths))
    # Calculate the mean spectral centroid
    centroids_all.append(np.mean(centroids))
# Create our X matrix
X = np.column_stack([means, stds, maxs, tempo_mean, tempo_max, tempo_std, bandwidths_all, centroids_all])
```

### **for your logistic regression models**

- One of the ways to improve accuracy is by **optimizing the prediction probability cutoff** scores generated by your logit model.
- You can **Normalize** all your features to the same scale before putting them in a machine learning model.
- Look for **class imbalance** in your data.
- You can **Optimize on other Metrics** also such as **Log Loss** and **F1-Score**.
- Tune the hyperparameters of your model. In the case of LogisticRegression, parameter $C$ is a hyperparameter.

Comment: thanks alot for giving your time :) the audio files have nearly no noise in it as they are specially recorded sounds from a mobile application of baby crying. i have tried normalizing the values in the array from the range of -1 to 1, TO 0 to 1. Moreover i have tried using ANN which uses spectrograms method and it gave me an accuracy of 100% after 100 epoches. The problem is that i cannot use spectrograms or MFCCs, kindly read my comments in the above question so you will have an idea. Well my data is imbalanced since 222 out of 581 audios are of baby crying. Thanks alot once again! :)

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar FFT is an efficient algorithm, and libraries for it are available for the arduino - see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djGOOL2mqV8